# Install wakatime plugin by pathogen in VIM

Tags: vim, wakatime

I've installed the plugin wakatime to keep track of my daily coding hours(I am using the package manager Pathogen). However, after installing it, I don't know where to enter my wakatime API key. If I understand it correctly, I should see some input that ask me to enter the API key after finishing installing the plugin, but I don't see it. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I haven't used wakatime, and yes from the README it could be understood, that you just can enter it. But i would have no idea where and how. But anyway after i quick look i find this https://github.com/wakatime/wakatime#configuring. So you should have a ~/.wakatime.cfg file, where you can configure all this stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will only ask for your API Key if it's not already saved. For example if you've already installed WakaTime in another IDE on your computer, then your API Key will already be saved to `$HOME/.wakatime.cfg` and installing more WakaTime plugins won't prompt for it again.

To edit your API Key in Vim, use this command:

`:WakaTimeApiKey`

Comment: Pretty useful to know that, because I setup wakatime on vim, after setting it up on sublime text. That's why I didn't get prompted for it. It's nice that the utility is smart about it, by reading it from the user's home dir. Awesome!

Answer (score 3):

Set up [pathogen.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen).

From terminal run :
`cd ~/.vim/bundle && git clone https://github.com/wakatime/vim-wakatime.git`
Open vim by typing `vim` in your terminal.
Now  you can type `:WakaTimeApiKey`, paste your secret **API-key** and press **Enter**. You might not be asked for your API Key if you have already installed another WakaTime plugin (for ATOM text editor for example).